# python docx will not work after convert from py to exe

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, docx, python-docx

I wrote this test.py to create a docx file for microsoft word. I run it well with python 3.6 interpreter. But when i convert test.py to test.exe by

```
pyinstaller -F -w -i "arkham_knight_poison_ivy_profile_Ptv_icon.ico" test.py
```

it will will error when launch test.exe. Here is my code

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document=Document()
document.add_heading("hello world")
document.add_paragraph("world is beautiful")
document.save('doc.docx')
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you launch test.exe?

Comment: Fatal error! Cannot run scripts test